# Adding files to an Azure Web Role publish

Tags: publish, azure-web-roles

I would like to add some extra files for use by an MVC web site when publishing an Azure Web Role. I use node.js to concatenate and minify certain javascript files that I use. Once minified I place them in a folder called "Built" that I place in the scripts folder. I would like to add this folder to the package that is published.

How do I add extra files when publishing to an Azure Web Role?

I do not want to use [this method](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2009/01/28/adding-files-to-your-windows-azure-service-package.aspx) as I don't want these files added to source control.